# How to access local Cloud Endpoints API from mobile device

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to access my Cloud Endpoints API hosted on my local dev machine from an Android app running on a mobile device I use for testing.

My device can access my dev machine by IP address. I passed --host=192.1.168.101 to the App Engine launcher so that my local App Engine instance binds to the IP address.  Although I can access the App Engine instance from 192.168.1.101, I get a 404 when my app makes an API call.

I noticed that going to `http://192.168.1.101:9080/_ah/api/explorer/` does not show my API; it redirects to `https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/`. If I use `http://localhost:9080/_ah/api/explorer/` I'm able to see my API as intended. It seems that using an IP address as the host is not working with Cloud Endpoints.

I'd rather not root my device to change its /etc/hosts file. Changing that might not be a solution anyway, since I'm unable to bind my App Engine instance to a hostname other than localhost.

This is my app.yaml config:

```
application: my-server
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: services.application

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the IP address. I needed to include a path in my API method decorator:

```
@endpoints.method(HelloRequest, HelloResponse, name='helloworld', path='test', http_method='GET')
    def helloworld(self, request):
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. I have @ApiMethod(name = "listMedia", path = "listMediaFiles") .. and always redirect me to developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p, are you sure isn't a problem related with IP address?

Answer (score 3):

You bound to your specific IP, but as a reminder, you can also bind to 0.0.0.0 (all available IPs). This is handy if you're using the maven appengine plugin and don't want to update the pom.xml file whenever your IP changes.

Next, make sure you're on the same network and can connect between the machines. I typically use ConnectBot to test by opening a telnet session to the IP address and port you defined for running locally. This will ensure your firewall isn't causing an issue.

Finally, update your code by adjusting the root url for your API. That would look something like this if your IP address were 192.168.1.100 and port were 8080:

```
Helloworld.Builder helloWorld = new Helloworld.Builder(AppConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
    AppConstants.JSON_FACTORY, credential);
helloWorld.setRootUrl("http://192.168.1.100:8080/_ah/api/");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your generated source code (usually the file named after your API name, such as [`Tictactoe.java`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-android/blob/master/src/com/google/api/services/tictactoe/Tictactoe.java)), `DEFAULT_ROOT_URL` should be set to `http://192.168.1.101:9080/_ah/api/`. This URL isn't expected to provide anything useful if you load it in a browser. Rather, it's the base of the path to your API requests, e.g. `http://192.168.1.101:9080/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/board`.

If you want to confirm your device is properly connecting to your local server (via your local network), load 
`http://192.168.1.101:9080/_ah/api/explorer/` from the device browser.

Comment: Going to http://192.168.1.101:9080/_ah/api/explorer/ does not show me my API-- it just redirects to https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/. If I use http://localhost:9080/_ah/api/explorer/ I can see my API just fine. Is this a bug?