# Google app engine has no response in local network after modify httpAddress

Tags: android, google-app-engine

i run google app engine sample SayHi  on localhost:8888 everything works.Then i want test on real android device so i need to change httpAddress to 0.0.0.0  in build.gradle .Page load  but request to endpoint (say hi button) has no response on other devices in local network besides that machine where app engine backend running .Why I not getting response on devices in local network ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your Run/Debug configurations in Android Studio aren't overriding the settings in the build.gradle?

[Run / Debug Configuarions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWio2.png)

See Run > Edit Configurations > App engine >

Check that the server address here is 0.0.0.0 or that synchonize with build.grade is selected if you have correctly edited the build.gradle.

Comment: i try both options still same result , not getting  response on 192.168.1.101:8888 (page load of course)

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651192/how-to-access-local-cloud-endpoints-api-from-mobile-device   , exactly  my problem but solution with add path not help me